# Android Studio 2.3.1 ; dependencies and sync project

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I installed the all new android studio and found a problem message 
"Failed To Open Zip File
Gradle`s depencies ....
Re-download depencies and sync project (requires network)
i don`t know what to do
thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

This mean that a file that Gradle has downloaded has become corrupted due to somehow or some reason. This might be the download of Gradle itself (which the wrapper does) or any dependency that Gradle has downloaded to run your build.

Gradle doesn't attempt to detect or resolve the problem, so you need to fix it manually. The solution is often to purge Gradle's download caches and let it get fresh copies of what it needs.

To do that, delete the .gradle directories in both your home directory and in your project's root directory and try building again.

In window home directory of gradle is

```
C:\Users\User\.gradle
```

In Mac OSX home directory

```
/Users/User_name/.gradle
```

Comment: Perfect Mate Thanx Very Much