# Error on android studio 2.3.1

Tags: android-studio

Gradle project sync failed when I'm running my project.

[image: here]

Comment: post your app gradle code .

Comment: NEVER post your code as an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 2.3.1 ; dependencies and sync project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403914/android-studio-2-3-1-dependencies-and-sync-project)

Answer (score 0):

Close your recommended gradle than go use define path from setting of projects. ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqXt2.png)